# Mercurial bookmark regex search?

Tags: mercurial

How to find a bookmark using a regular expression?

Answer (score 3):

The command:

```
hg log -r bookmark('re:T.+v2')
```

lists all bookmarks matching the regex `T.+v2`.

---

In TortoiseHG:

- Press `Ctrl+S` to show the *Filter Toolbar*
- Write `bookmark('re:T.+v2')`.

---

This is documented under [Patterns and Predicates](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/doc/hg.1.html#specifying-revisions) as part of the *revsets* query language.